# Vault GCP Project Level Role Binding

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hashicorp-vault, google-iam

I am trying to apply the role binding below to grant the Storage Admin Role to a GCP roleset in Vault.

```
resource "//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/{project_id_number}" {
  roles = [
    "roles/storage.admin"
  ]
}
```

I want to grant access to the project level, not a specific bucket so that the GCP roleset can access and read/write to the Google Container Registry.

When I try to create this roleset in Vault, I get this error:

```sh
Error writing data to gcp/roleset/my-roleset: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/gcp/roleset/my-roleset
Code: 400. Errors:

* unable to set policy: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission
```

My Vault cluster is running in a GKE cluster which has OAuth Scopes for all Cloud APIs, I am the project owner, and the service account Vault is using has the following permissions:

- Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter
- Service Account Actor
- Service Account Admin
- Service Account Key Admin
- Service Account Token Creator
- Logs Writer
- Storage Admin
- Storage Object Admin

I have tried giving the service account both Editor and Owner roles, and I still get the same error.

Firstly, am I using the correct resource to create a roleset for the Storage Admin Role at the project level?

Secondly, if so, what could be causing this permission error?

Answer (score 0):

I had previously recreated the cluster and skipped this step:

```
vault write gcp/config credentials=@credentials.json
```

Adding the key file fixed this.

There is also a chance that following the steps to create a custom role [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/hashicorp-vault-secrets-generate-service-account-credentials/index.html?index=..%2F..hashiconf-us-18#4) and adding that custom role played a part.